# How do you set a custom default unique id string for the @PrimaryGeneratedColumn in a TypeORM Entity?

Tags: javascript, entity, typeorm

I have a use case that calls for a custom string primary key in my tables. (I don't want to use the default 'uuid' provided by GraphQL, but instead want to use the [shortid library](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) to generate a custom unique id instead.)

I'm a TypeORM beginner, and I'm not finding anything about setting a custom default primary key in the docs. Is it possible to achieve what I want in the TypeORM PrimaryGeneratedColumn, or do I have to accomplish what I want by other means?

UPDATE: I learned I can use the [@BeforeInsert listener](http://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/beforeinsert) to modify entities before saving them, but TypeORM still doesn't let me override the PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') and use a shortId string because the shortId string is not a valid uuid.

Comment: Depending on which database you are using, specifing `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')` means that the database field type will be `uuid`, which you can't insert a non-valid UUID in. I'd suggest decorating with [@PrimaryColumn('char', { length: <shortId length> })](http://typeorm.io/#decorator-reference/primarycolumn) and using a `@BeforeInsert` listener as you describe. This will give you a fixed-length character primary key for the shortId.

Comment: Looking again at the shortId docs, I noticed that the generated ID may be variable length; if so you'll want to use `@PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: <max-shortid-length> })` instead of the above...

Comment: @PrimaryColumn is exactly what I needed. I'm such a noob I didn't even know PrimaryColumn was a decorator :# my code ended up looking like this `@PrimaryColumn('varchar', { default: shortid.generate(), length: 14 })` thanks for your help! 

I'd vote up your comments but it won't let me :/

Comment: Posted as answer so you can up-vote it! BTW with the column `default` option, are you passing the function itself (ie `default: shortid.generate`) or calling it and defaulting to its return value (`default: shortid.generate()`)? Unless I'm mistaken you'll need the former - otherwise TypeORM will have a single default value each time your app starts and will allow inserting one record but then error with a duplicate key violation for subsequent records.

Comment: @Timshel you are correct, I ran into duplicate key violation. However, when I tried the change you recommended, I kept running into a `column "gz68lzqnmn" does not exist` (the id changes each time) error. The only way around this I found was to keep `default: shortid.generate()` but then in the BeforeInsert hook I added `this.id = shortid.generate()`. Very hacky and sad :( but it works.

If you want to look further into this you could pull this repo and `yarn start` to reproduce. No pressure though. Thanks again!

https://github.com/podverse/podverse-api/tree/primaryDefaultBug

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a quoting issue - the returned ID isn't quoted so is being interpreted as a column. Wrapping `shortid.generate()` and quoting the value should be all that is needed - e.g. ``default: () => `'${shortid.generate()}'` `` (note the single quotes around the ID).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')` decorator maps the column to a `uuid` database field type if the database supports it, which means the column values must be a valid UUIDs.

For your scenario I suggest decorating with:
`` typescript
@PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: <max shortId length>, default: () => `'${shortid.generate()}'` }) ``

Answer (score 7):

@Timshel's answer does not work when using SQLite, because default values must be constant. It gives the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: SQLITE_ERROR: default value of column [id] is not constant
```

Instead, you can use [@BeforeInsert](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeinsert) to achieve the desired result, like so:

```
@Field(() => ID)
@PrimaryColumn("varchar", {
  length: 20
})
id: string;

@BeforeInsert()
setId() {
  this.id = shortid.generate();
}
```

Comment: @Timshel's answer also doesn't work for most other drivers. I tested it out using MySQL and when I created a migration from my entity the migration included: `ALTER TABLE user CHANGE id id char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 177f7044-0805-4891-870e-8352cffa77bf`. Looks like if you want TypeORM to do the value generation you have to use `@BeforeInsert`

Comment: other problem arises as it's either not possible to update entities OR its possible to expose a way to create entities with arbitrary IDs

Comment: Please note that you have to pass an instance of the entity (and not a plain object) to the `save()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Great thanks to the answers from [Timshel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440110/timshel) and 
[Oskari Liukku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12712876/oskari-liukku)!

There is a complementary to their answer.

Recently, `shortid` was ***depricated***, and on their main page they recommend to use `nanoid`.

[nanoid on npm](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/)

Comment: But what if nanoid will create id with the same value? You wil get an error, no?